# Simple formula difficult solution

Tags: functions

I've thinking a lot about it, but is there a simple way to get

$\frac{A}{C}$

from

$X = \frac{A + B}{C + D}$

where it does not depend on A and C anymore? This seems so easy but it's quite hard for me.

Some elaboration (after comment below):

I originally have some function

$X_{ori} = \frac{A}{C}$

and calculate an error on one input such that it yields

$X_{err} = \frac{A + B}{C + D}$

but in order to get $\delta$ from

$X_{err} = X_{ori} + \delta$

I need to have the above conversion.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question a little bit.

Comment: I added some information about my problem

Comment: If you do not have $B$ and $D$, then it is impossible

Comment: if $B$ and $D$ are very small in comparison to $A$ and $B$ then you can ignore them as negligible.  Otherwise, you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

For your given $X_{err}$ and $X_{ori}$, you have $$\delta=X_{err}-X_{ori}=\frac{A+B}{C+D}-\frac{A}{C}=\frac{BC-AD}{C(C+D)}.$$

Does that answer your question?